# String manipulation in Excel sheet formula

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula

Cell A4 has latitude and longitudes like this 33.7998709,-84.3432666.

I want cell A5 should have **getMap(33.7998709,-84.3432666);**

Please see attached image.

[image]

But I am getting #VALUE! **error!**

How can I get this formatted string in the cell next to A4?

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot with the actual cell names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cell A5

```
=CONCATENATE("getMap(",A4,");")
```